# what is this electrical component in my thermocouple?

Tags: hot-water, natural-gas

I have a 14 year old has water heater which i believe needs a new thermocouple. I can relight the pilot but it will not stay lit.

I've bought a new thermocouple, and I'm prepared to replace the old one, but I'm a bit hesitant due to the part picture here.

[image: odd electrical component]

My new thermocouple doesn't have this. Is it some sort of resistor? Would it be dangerous to install the new thermocouple without this piece?

Any advice is much appreciated.

Update: this is a closeup of the thing, it fell off

[image]

Comment: That looks like some kind of safety, what brand / model of water heater. I don’t remember seeing anything like that on any units I have installed. It may be a protection from the high voltage ignition circuit like a high temp diode that dumps the spikes to ground, left as a comment because that is a guess.

Comment: The brand is State, the model GS640YBRS. I was messing around with it trying to see if it was a resistor and then it fell off. It has some lettering on it "UHM" seems like the brand, and the U9187 is the model, but googling around i couldn't figure out what it is.

Comment: In Europe, seals look similar. Is it heavy, made of lead? The numbers on it could be pressed by a tool after installation coding the (certified) installer and date. There is enough room left for the tool. The S-type wire with a white coating is of 2 separate parts or is it one piece?

Comment: Looks like a thermal cutoff. Look around to see if it was originally clamped against something.